# How do I change the value of a textview inserted programmatically in android?

Tags: android, button, onclick, textview

It's a digital menu with n number of products, the products themselves are inserted into an horizontalScrollView with values: quantity, optional items, etc...

I want that by clicking a button, the number value displayed in the TextView would increase / decrease ...

Is it possible?

```
...    
  for(int l=0; l<jsonarraySub.length(); l++){
        JSONObject obj = jsonarraySub.getJSONObject(l);

        String stIdProd = obj.getString("codigo");

        TextView qtd = new TextView(CardapioActivity.this);
        qtd.setText("1");
        qtd.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        qtd.setId(Integer.parseInt(stIdProd));
        qtd.setTextSize((float) 20);

        rl4.addView(qtd);
...

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsMenos = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70,66);
        paramsMenos.topMargin = 322;
        paramsMenos.leftMargin = x+640; 
        menos[l].setLayoutParams(paramsMenos);
        menos[l].setId(Integer.parseInt(stIdProd));
        menos[l].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnmenos);

        menos[l].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
               setMenos(stIdProd);  
            }   
        });

}
...

/*Decrease value of a textview
 */
 public void setMenos(String id){

     ????

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What you want to increase is "qtd" object???

Comment: just use .setText() to set the text to the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the TextView you're creating you manually set the ID yourself.

```
qtd.setId(Integer.parseInt(stIdProd));
```

Because you're setting the IDs yourself, and you're passing that ID to setMenos, you should be able to find the TextView you're trying to change.

Have you tried something like this?

```
/*Decrease value of a textview
 */
 public void setMenos(String id){

  TextView thisView = (TextView) findViewByID(Integer.parseInt(id));
  Int currVal = Integer.parseInt(thisView.getText());

  currVal--;

  thisView.setText(currVal.toString());

 }
```

Comment: hi, thanks.
it seems that he does not think the TextView with the ID passed..
tried using that way, but it shows me:
`07-31 17:09:06.556: E/AndroidRuntime(13118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 17:09:06.556: E/AndroidRuntime(13118): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""...
`

Comment: I can think of some other ways to format the code, but first I wonder if all your IDs you're setting are actually numerical? If you change `String stIdProd = obj.getString("codigo");` to `Int stIdProd = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("codigo"));`, and update references to `stIdProd` to not have to parseInt, do you still get the error?

Comment: Yes, it really is an integer value. 
changing `String stIdProd = obj.getString("codigo"); to Int stIdProd = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("codigo"));` it worked for me, thanks ... but is the question, why? basically would not be the same thing? thank you very much for the help

Comment: It should be the same thing, but you end up calling Integer.parseInt every time you reference stIdProd. Nowhere in this code did you every use stIdProd as a String, so there's no point storing it as a String and converting it every time. If you can store stIdProd as an Int successfully, then you know you'll be able to use it as an Int from there on out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the existing value of a TextView and decrease here is what you should do.

```
  /*Decrease value of a textview
 */
 public void setMenos(String id){

     TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(Integer.parseInt(id)); 
     int i = Integer.parseInt(view.getText());
     i--;
     view.setText(i);

 }
```

Hopefully this helps some, if not feel free to comment and clarify what you'd like.